# Heuristic for a density conjecture related to the Collatz $(3x+1)$-problem

Tags: open-problems, collatz-conjecture, heuristics

First, some notation. Define $T(n)$ over $n\in \mathbb{N}$ as:
$$
T(n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{}
    3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}\ \\
    n/2, & \text{if $n$ is even}
  \end{array} \right.
$$

And let:
$$
\pi_a(x) = \#\{ n : n\leq x \mbox{ and } T^j(n) = a \mbox{ for some $j$ }\}
$$

Of course, the classic Collatz conjecture is that $\pi_1(x) = x$ for all $x$.

A succession of papers (see references below) have established bounds on $\pi_a(x)$ of the form: For $a \not\equiv 0 \; (\mbox{mod } 3)$,
$$
\pi_a(x) \geq x^\gamma, \; \forall x \geq x_0(a)
$$
The cases where $a \equiv 0\; (\mbox{mod } 3)$ are generally uninteresting for these questions since we know that the set $\{n : T^j(n) = a\}$ is precisely $\{2^k a : k=0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

In [1], the authors state the following conjecture (though I'm uncertain if they originated this conjecture or if there are earlier citations for it):

$$
\text{Conjecture A}:\mbox{For each $a\not\equiv 0 \;(\mbox{mod } 3)$, there is a positive constant $c_a$ such that}\\
\pi_a(x) \geq c_a x, \; \forall x \geq a 
$$

There appears to be at least a tiny bit of empirical data to support this conjecture. Some arithmetic reveals that the last odd number (not including 1) in a Collatz trajectory must be of the form ${2^{2k}-1}\over{3}$. I took a pseudo-random sample of 10,000,000 numbers in the interval $[0, 2^m-1]$ for each $m \in \{64,128,256,512,1024,2048\}$ and recorded the last odd number in each  trajectory. The results are summarized in the table below:
$$
\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 \; &   m=64    &   128 &   256 &   512 &   1024    &   2048 \\
\hline 
k=2 &   9377219 &   9377605 &   9376867 &   9377728 &   9378367 &   9377611 \\
4   &   238003  &   237079  &   238246  &   237240  &   237296  &   237829 \\
5   &   378816  &   379476  &   379021  &   379013  &   378382  &   378506 \\
7   &   787 &   782 &   783 &   760 &   808 &   831 \\
8   &   4839    &   4736    &   4762    &   4916    &   4814    &   4896 \\
10  &   311 &   295 &   310 &   322 &   317 &   307 \\ 
11  &   21  &   24  &   9   &   19  &   15  &   17  \\
13  &   3   &   2   &   2   &   1   &   0   &   2 \\
14  &   1   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   1 \\
\end{array}
$$

> **Question**: Is there any intution or heuristic that supports Conjecture A? Or, if not for the conjecture in full generality, at least for these set of "last" odd numbers of the form ${2^{2k}-1}\over {3}$, $ k\not\equiv0(\mbox{mod }3)$?

By "intuition or heuristic", I'm thinking of perhaps something in the same vein as this [probabilistic heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#A_probabilistic_heuristic) for why the Collatz conjecture itself should be true.

---

1. *Applegate, David; Lagarias, Jeffrey C.*, [**Density bounds for the (3x+1) problem. I: Tree-search method. II: Krasikov inequalities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2153345), Math. Comput. 64, No. 209, 411-426, 427-438 (1995). [ZBL0820.11006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0820.11006).
2. *Crandall, R. E.*, [**On the ”3x+1” problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2006353), Math. Comput. 32, 1281-1292 (1978). [ZBL0395.10013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0395.10013).
3. *Krasikov, I.*, [**How many numbers satisfy the (3x+1) conjecture?**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/S0161171289000979), Int. J. Math. Math. Sci. 12, No. 4, 791-796 (1989). [ZBL0685.10008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0685.10008).
4. *Krasikov, Ilia; Lagarias, Jeffrey C.*, [**Bounds for the (3x+1) problem using difference inequalities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa109-3-4), Acta Arith. 109, No. 3, 237-258 (2003). [ZBL1069.11011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1069.11011).
5. *Sander, J. W.*, [**On the ((3N+1))-conjecture**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa-55-3-241-248), Acta Arith. 55, No. 3, 241-248 (1990). [ZBL0707.11017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0707.11017).
6. *Wirsching, Günther*, [**An improved estimate concerning (3n+1) predecessor sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa-63-3-205-210), Acta Arith. 63, No. 3, 205-210 (1993). [ZBL0804.11022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0804.11022).

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have the reference but if we think of some conventional integer $x$ as drawn from the 2-adic integers and suppose its Collatz sequence diverges then let $Q(x)$ be the function from $\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$ that sends any 2-adic integer to the sequence of parities $\pmod 2$ of its successors $T^n(x)$ then it turns out the density of ones in that sequence is greater than $\log_3(2)$ if and only if $x$ is positive. This appears perhaps similar or related to the heuristic you require.